# How can I access array items inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, mapping

I have an array which contains multiple objects (which have their own array of objects inside them). What I'm trying to do is map through each object's "subMenuItems" array and output the values inside.

Here's my Array:

```
export const MenuItems = [
  {
    category: 'Buy',
    subMenuItems: [
      {
        title: `Watching`,
        link: '/watching',
      },
      {
        title: `Bids & Offers`,
        link: '/bids-offers',
      },
      {
        title: `Bought`,
        link: '/bought',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    category: 'Sell',
    subMenuItems: [
      {
        title: `Selling`,
        link: '/selling',
      },
      {
        title: `Sold`,
        link: '/sold',
      },
      {
        title: `Sell with us`,
        link: '/sell-with-us',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm able to get each object's category no problem by doing this:

```
  const listItems = MenuItems.map((item, i) => (
    <li key={i}>{item.category}</li>
  ));


Render:
return(
<ul>{listItems}</ul>
)
```

However I can't seem to get the syntax right when trying to access the "subMenuItems" in each object.

My end goal is to have a function that returns each category with it's sub menu items below it:
E.G.

```
Buy

 - Watching
 - Bids & offers
 - Bought

Sell

 - Selling
 - Sold
 - Sell With Us
```

Hope that makes sense :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing and render them using `.map`:

```
  const listItems = MenuItems.map((item, i) => (
    <li key={i}>
     {item.category}
     <ul>
       {item.subMenuItems?.map((index, subMenu) => (
         <li key={subMenu.title}> // index as key can be problematic 
            <a href={subMenu.link}>{subMenu.title}</a>
         </li>
       )}
     </ul>
    </li>
  ));
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for your help! Quick question, what is the puropose of the '?' after the item.subMenuitems ?

Comment: @Connor It's the "optional chaining operator": [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` the `subMenuItems` into a `ul` and add it to your outer `li`

```
const listItems = MenuItems.map((item, i) => (
    const itemlist = item.subMenuItems.map((a, b) => (
        <li key={a.title}><a href={a.link}>{a.title}</a></li>
    ));
    <li key={i}>{item.category}<ul>{itemlist}</ul></li>
));
```